# Unit testing a controller that contains custom validation

Tags: java, spring, validation, unit-testing

I am trying to make a unit test for my controller.
Here's a method from my controller that I want to test:

```
public class SomeController {

    @Autowired public RequestValidator reqValidator;
    @Autowired public SomeService service;

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/Inquiry", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String inquiry(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @ModelAttribute Request req, BindingResult bindingResult) {

        reqValidator.validate(req, bindingResult);
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return something;
        }
        return service.inquiry(req);
    }
}
```

ReqValidator is custom validator I implement to check if each of the request field is null, too long, and some other things that I cant achieve with hibernate validator.

Anyway, I am doing alrigth with testing the success scenario of this method. Here's my test method.

```
public class SomeControllerTest {

    @Mock private RequestValidator reqValidator;
    @Mock private SomeService service;
    @InjectMocks private SomeController controller;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testInquiry_success() throws Exception {
    when(service.inquiry(any(Request.class))).thenReturn(res);
    mockMvc.perform(get("/Inquiry")
            .param("email", "john.doe@gmail.com")
            .param("phoneNumber", "01189998819991197253")
            )
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string(res));
    }
}
```

The above test went well. But I am stuck when I wanted to test for the negative scenarios, e.g. one of the field is empty. The test never seem to enter the reqValidator.validate() method. Even if I make the email and phone number empty. How do I get to test the negative scenarios? How do I get my test to enter the validation?

Below is my custom validation class which implements spring's Validator.

```
@Component
public class RequestValidator implements Validator {

    // omitted to be concise

    @Override
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
        // validate something
    }
}
```

I hope I explain my self well.
Thank you.

Comment: The test code looks incomplete.  Where is mockMvc and service coming from?  Can you post the complete code? It looks like you're mocking out service and somehow mockMvc is interacting with it.

Comment: I've editted the code.

Comment: Which mocking framework are you using?

Comment: Im using mockito and junit

Answer (score 0):

Your unit test never actually called the `reqValidator.validate()` method because `reqValidator.validate()` is a void method.

In mockito, void method on mocks does nothing by default. As mentioned in [doNothing()](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doNothing()) docs. If you want to actually run the void method, you can use [doCallRealMethod()](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doCallRealMethod()).

Comment: but to actually run the void method is kind of bad for unit testing, isn't it? because as i understand, unit testing is supossed to be isolated within one class only